# Guidelines to avoid multithreaded problems

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing a game where each object has its own thread where it moves and does its operations.
I got a central object that coordinates all interaction between all objects. I've ran into multiple problems with random object just doing random things at random times and I can't reproduce these, they happen in about 1 in 100 runs. I even got a cases where impossible things happen - a field is written to in middle of the program where the only statement that writes to is at the start of the program.
What guidelines can I follow to fix this without flattering all threads by locking the central object at each pass. I don't want to flattern them because it will cause "accordion" movement. To reference accordion movement is when objects 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 need to move right and that happens (time is progressing downwards).

```
54321
5432 1
543 21
54 321
5 4321
 54321
```

EDIT: Just a clarification:
I use a framework that I think makes a thread for each object, I can't control that. All objects are called their update function in succesion and I figured out it does some of them in parallel after I got some errors that happen in multithreaded code. It might pool the threads or assign a number of objects for each thread to update but I can't be sure unless you can show me how to figure this out in the scientific method.

Comment: How many threads do you have?

Comment: About 100, can grow to few thousands in stress moments.

Comment: If you want correctness, a lock is the easiest way. Try that first before worrying about contention.

Comment: A few thousand threads seems a *bit* high...

Comment: @forsvarir I'm using a framework that automatically assigns a thread to each object, and when bullets fly all over in the game its kind of hard to avoid high thread count.

Comment: @Dani: Assuming bullets have collision detection... it seems like coordinating that across a large number of threads would be hard... Doesn't the framework you're using provide some kind of guide as to how to coordinate the instantiated threads?

Comment: bullets don't have collision, nothing has collisions, physics is completely disabled. Its just path-finding(A*, and flood fills) on a dynamic map and bullets following the units.

Comment: @Dani: I've posted an answer... it's not really an answer, but it doesn't fit in a comment either..

Comment: @Dani: You can check the number of threads by breaking in visual studio (assuming that's what you're using) and looking at the active threads (debug menu, windows, threads)... Are you using a publicly available framework (if so, what's it called)? If the 'Update' doesn't contain a loop, it's unlikely to be one thread per object.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: "a game where each object has its own thread" - very wrong use of Threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all. Using a few hundred threads makes your program ***slower***. Using thousand threads is just horrible. You should really reconsider your application design. The ThreadPool might be a better fit?

Here is a great article explaining all threading concepts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx

> As I said in the comment I use a framework that automatically makes threads, I have no control over that

Well. Then you must be using the framework incorrectly. There is no way any game framework developer has made something so that it creates hundreds of threads per design.

Answer (score 2):

Primarily: don't use multithreading unnecessarily, since parallelism is hard, as you are starting to discover (look at e.g. [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)). If you think threading solves a problem, use a thread workpool to scale with the number of processors/cores, not with your problem size (number of objects).

In your specific case: isolate physics and object interactions from rendering. I suspect you can do all your object changes in one sweep (and in a single thread), and then render them, avoiding any accordionicity(!).

Comment: As I said in the comment I use a framework that automatically makes threads, I have no control over that.

Comment: Consider switching frameworks, then. Even if it may make sense in some contexts with very few objects, the framework is clearly unsuitable to your requirements, if you truly have no alternative to threading each object. But... check the documentation.